# Is it ok to ask questions about mythicism, the notion that Jesus did not exist?

Tags: discussion

I see there are a couple of related questions, but not mine in particular. I am trying to find a reason to take seriously the notion that Richard Carrier and a few other experts can refute the consensus among biblical scholars -- Bart Ehrman has said (I heard him say it myself) that no reputable scholar in either Europe or North America doubts the existence of the man Jesus.

I would also like to understand why anyone would attempt to prove a negative, which, at least as I understand logic, is not possible.

Is christianity.stackexchange.com a suitable forum for such questions?

Comment: It is certainly possible to prove a negative- sometimes even necessary. In an _indirect proof_, instead of showing that the conclusion to be proved is true, you show that all of the alternatives are false. To do this, you must _assume the negation_ of the statement to be proved. Then, deductive reasoning will lead to a contradiction. That is, if I wanted to indirectly prove that Jesus existed, I would assume that he did not exist, then follow that line of reasoning to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: A good argument, thanks. But help me to understand: if assumed the negative case, and could not find a contradiction, that wouldn't prove the negative, would it? I mean, it would be suggestive, but it wouldn't prove it?

Comment: Failing to find a contradiction would not prove the negative unless you could demonstrate that no possible source of contradiction was overlooked- the method of demonstrating that all alternatives are false is only (most?) useful if one can rigorously enumerate all alternatives. I think that is generally impossible with respect to historical queries. However, assuming the negation of a statement under evaluation and following deductive reasoning to its terminus is a useful practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Probably not**. The caveat being that questions about (particular) *Christian* arguments (for or) against such a view can be on-topic ([a somewhat related example](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34750/are-there-christians-who-believe-jesus-was-an-ideology-and-not-a-person)). I don't pretend that this opinion represents the entire Christianity.SE community, but I believe that dissenters will be in the minority here (Perhaps someone else will argue the *for* case and the voting will give a clearer indication). The basic reason is that this notion is not (as far as I'm aware) a doctrine held by any (self-identifying) Christian groups. It could charitably be described as an academic theory, or less so as an atheistic dogma; in either case it's not really within our purview. Skeptics has a strong counter argument [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/1650/19195), so I don't think that's an appropriate place either, but perhaps this is more on-topic at either [philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com) or [history.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks so much, that's a very thoughtful answer, and a very good point about there being no Christian groups who would hold that position. Thank you.

Comment: I think Skeptics would be appropriate, but answers may not support Carrier's arguments there either.

Comment: Skeptics will just appeal to authority in the answers.

Comment: History.SE might work, if your goal is to examine the historical evidence in favor of a particular view.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks. From what I can tell, the mythicist view is based on a lack of historical evidence. But I'll check out that SE, thanks.